# #1044 - Access denied for user 'buriedse'@'%' to database 'buriedse_root'

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

[image: screenshot]

i tried everything possible to fix this but nothing worked for me ,pls help me to create a table on my database .

Answer (score 0):

AS your question title says, the error is a clear problem with your user autentication. This problem may be due to a very large list of causes, but I will give you what in my humble opinion is a quick troubleshooting that may lead you to solve this problem:

- First of all, check the permissions of your user on the specified database. Using SQL Server Management Studio, right click your user, properties, then user mapping. Right there you have to check for the correct database mapping and the desired role.
- Check server authentication mode, to see if it is on mixed mode. In many cases, I´ve seen many installations where the authentication is set to windows only, and users keep getting this message having the correct permissions on user and correct mappings.

Comment: make a script of your user and post it on your question

Comment: @Nithinshah I cannot do nothing with your credentials, you have to solve the code on your own